# Need a alternative to key.equals() java

Tags: java

Is there any alternatives to key.equals() thing in Java . here is the code where i need the alternative

```
   public boolean containsElement(String personalIdNo)
{
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList <String>> entry : applications.entrySet())
    {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        if (key.equals(personalIdNo))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Does this code not work?

Comment: Why do you need an alternative? What's going wrong with `.equals()`?

Comment: it looks like you've reimplemented `Map.containsKey(Object key)`, only slower, and backwards as @R.J points out below.

Comment: Method name says `containsElement` but you return `false` if the key matches with the element. Why is that so?

Comment: wouldn't `applications.containsKey(personalIdNo)` do what you intend to do in that method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Map` interface supplies the [`containsKey` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29).  Try

```
!applications.containsKey(personalIdNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? It is considered hard to answer questions without knowing the exact question.

To me it currently seems that you are implementing behaviour that already exists:

- I think you have a `Map<String, List<String>> applications` object somewhere in your application.
- It seems that you want to return whether or not a key exists.

For that you can simply use: `applications.containsKey(personalIdNo);`.
This does exactly what you seem to be wanting.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really an alternative, `.equals()` is the comparing function you want. There is also `.equalsIgnoreCase()` if you want to compare without case.

Another note, you can simply return like so:

```
return !key.equals(personalIdNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

i can see the key is a `String`, depending on your requirements you can use `==` (for object reference comparison and) and `.equals()`(and similar equalsIgnoreCase() methods) (for object value comparison.) there is no other alternative for comparison